# Get Model and id of the Model you are adding a note to

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, model, polymorphism

Basically,

I have a notes table with a polymorphic relationship with videos and users and want to determine how on my store method in my NotesController I get which model I am added a note to, and the id in that table. This is my create query on my store method

```
       $note = Note::query()->create([
            'body' => $request->get('body'),
            'user_id' => \Auth::id(),
            'noteable_id' => 1, **(needs to be dynamic)**
            'noteable_type' => Video::class, **(needs to be dynamic)**
        ]);
```

Blade

```
                    <form action="{{route('admin.note.store'}}" method="post">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input id="btn-input" name="body" required="true" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message here...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-chat">
                                    Submit
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Essentially I want to know how I can retrieve the noteable_type = (Model I'm updating) and the noteable_id (id of the record I'm adding a note to)

Is there any way of retrieving this dynamically on the request?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your blade template that you're getting the request from as well?

Comment: Added to the original post

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the video or any other model some way. If your route contains the video id then you can use that in your controller. Here are some ways you can do this.

```
//Get your video model
$video = Video::find(...);

$note = \Auth::user()->create([
    'body' => $request->get('body'),
    'noteable_id' => $video->id,
    'noteable_type' => get_class($video),
]);

// OR

$note = new Note([
    'body' => $request->get('body'),
    'user_id' => \Auth::id(),
]);

$video->note()->save($note);
```

Run `php artisan route:list` and post it so that i can advise you on how to fetch the model.